# creating dictionaries to list order of ranking

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of people and who controls who but I need to combine them all and form several sentences to compute which person control a list of people.

The employee order comes from a `txt` file:

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

controls = defaultdict(list)

with open('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        controller, controlled = line.strip().split(' controls ')
        controls[controller].append(controlled)

print 'employee order:'
for controller, controlled in controls.iteritems():       
    if len(controlled) > 1:
        conjoined = ', '.join(controlled[:-1])
        conjoined = '{} and {}'.format(conjoined, controlled[-1])
    else:
        conjoined = controlled[0]
    print '{} controls {}'.format(controller, conjoined)
```

Comment: what would defaultdict be ?

Comment: @user3467226 https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects

Comment: when trying to run the program it gives this error    controller, controllee = line.split(' controls ')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: That means your example text file in the question doesn't contain what you said it does.

Comment: could there be some spelling error? nvm i had to change data.txt to mine and now when i run it it is completly blank

Comment: there should be a print command in it but what would the item we would be printing?

Comment: The code above creates a dictionary, where the keys are the controller and the values are a list of people they control. Try `print controls` at the end of the script to see it. I thought this would be enough for you to work out the rest.

Comment: ohh okay i see the list has been created but i need to make it so it displays as a sentence saying for ex.a controls b,c and d. thanks.

Comment: if i need to have 2 txt files and the users picks which one they want to use would i just alter open('data.txt') with open(input('enter file:')

Comment: Before the `with` statement, add something like `input_file = input('enter filename:')`. If you're using Python 2.x, that should be `raw_input`.

Comment: i keep getting defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [' b\n'], 'a ': [' c\n']}) how would i change this?

Comment: It's a dictionary, with keys and values, which you can format however you like. But as these comments are getting too long I've just updated the code above. I highly recommend you read through a Python tutorial.