# creating dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of people and who controls who but I need to combine them all and form several sentences to compute which person control a list of people.

The employee order comes from a `txt` file:

a controls b
a controls c
a controls d
b controls c
d controls e
d controls f
e controls f

I know that I have to create a dictionary that loads the `txt` file into it but I am stuck. 
Any ideas on how to do this??

Comment: Is this the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980434/creating-dictionaries-to-list-order-of-ranking)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Read the file line by line.
- Extract the first and last words of each line as a tuple in a list.
- Process the elements of this list and create a dictionary

  ```
  afile = open('filename')
  tuple_data = []
  for line in afile:
      a = line.strip().split()
      tuple_data.append((a[0].strip(), a[-1].strip()))
  ```

`tuple_data` now has:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('d', 'f'), ('e', 'f')]
```

Now use defaultdict to build the output:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> output = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x, y in tuple_data:
...     output[x].append(y)
...
>>> output
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['c'], 'e': ['f'], 'd': ['e', 'f']})
```

Now you can print out the output as:

```
print 'Employee order:'
for k, v in output.items():
    values = ','.join(v)
    print '\t{} controls {}'.format(k, values)
```

Comment: how would i make it so every last value has a "and" before it instead of a "," and also if i wanted to use any different text i wanted would i just change it to afile = open(input('filename'))